# publish message to tibco jms queue using c#

Tags: c#, jms, tibco

I have the below information:

```
`JNDIFactoryClass - com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory`
`JNDIServiceURL - tibjmsnaming://<Host>:<PORT>`
`JMSConnectionFactory - A**.**.***.COMMON.QCF.MS`
`UserName - <UserName>`
`Password - <Password>`
`QUEUEName - <QUEUENAME>`
```

I have to publish a message to this queue using c#. Please help

I have tried using weblogic.messaging dll but it didn't work

Added the below code:

```
IDictionary<string, Object> paramMap = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

            // add necessary properties

            paramMap[WebLogic.Messaging.Constants.Context.PROVIDER_URL] = txtJNDIServiceURL.Text; //"t3://" + host + ":" + port;

            paramMap[WebLogic.Messaging.Constants.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL] = txtJMSUserName.Text;//username;

            paramMap[WebLogic.Messaging.Constants.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS] = txtJMSPassword.Text;


            // get the initial context


            IContext context = ContextFactory.CreateContext(paramMap);



            // lookup the connection factory

            IConnectionFactory cf = context.LookupConnectionFactory(txtJNDIFactoryClass.Text);

            // lookup the queue

            IQueue queue = (IQueue)context.LookupDestination(txtJMSQueue.Text);

            // create a connection

            IConnection connection = cf.CreateConnection();

            // start the connection

            connection.Start();

            // create a session

            ISession session = connection.CreateSession(

            WebLogic.Messaging.Constants.SessionMode.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // create a message producer

            IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(queue);

            producer.DeliveryMode = WebLogic.Messaging.Constants.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT;

            // create a text message

            ITextMessage textMessage = session.CreateTextMessage(rtbTriggerMsg.Text);

            // send the message

            producer.Send(textMessage);

            // CLEAN UP

            connection.Close();

            context.CloseAll();
```

Comment: Any code to show? What do yo mean by _"but it didn't work"_?  Please see [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Added code some one please look into this